# BASH: Split strings without any delimiter and keep only first sub-string

Tags: regex, bash, csv, split

I have a CSV file containing 7 columns and I am interested in modifying only the first column. In fact, in some of the rows a row name appears *n* times in a concatenated way without any space. I need a script that can identify where the duplication starts and remove all duplications.

**Example of a row name among others**:

Row name = `EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4`

Replace by: `EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4`

In the different rows:

- *n* can vary
- The length of the row name can vary
- The structure of the row name can vary (eg. amount of `_` and `.`), but it is always collated without any space

**What I have tried:**

```
:%s/(.+)\1+/\1/
```

Step-by-step:

- `%s`: substitute in the whole file
- `(.+)\1+`: First capturing group. `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators), `+` is the quantifier — matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.
- `\1+`:  matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
- Substitute by `\1`

However, I get the following errors:

- E65: Illegal back reference
- E476: Invalid command

Comment: What is the tool that gives these errors? The command you posted does what you expect when using with sed:  `sed -E 's/(.+)\1+/\1/' file`

Comment: @oliv Looks like vi/Vim?

Comment: You have to escape: `:%s/\(.\+\)\1\+/\1/`

Comment: @BenjaminW. This is what I thought, and tried it, but I just don't get these errors...

Comment: @oliv I got them, for unescaped `()`, and then for unescaped `+`, but it might depend on the specific version you use.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you need only one line contain `EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4`. In that case you can do the following:

First remove duplicates in one line:

```
sed -i "s/EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4.*/EXAMPLE1.ABC_DEF.panel4/g"
```

Then remove duplicated lines:

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: Thank you @Nasr for your answer. However this is not exactly what I was looking for. The CSV file has rows with different row names. So I am trying to rename all rows where the name is appearing in a duplicated form. I hope it is explained better this time.

Answer (score 0):

If all your rows are of the format you gave in the question (like `EXAMPLExyzEXAMPLExyz`) then this should work-

```
awk -F"EXAMPLE" '{print FS $2}' file
```

This takes "EXAMPLE" as the field delimiter and asks it to print only the first 'column'. It prepends "EXAMPLE" to this first column (by calling the inbuilt `awk` variable `FS`). Thanks, @andlrc.

Not an ideal solution but may be good enough for this purpose.

Comment: I think using a multichar as field separator is a GNU extension. You can use the
variable `FS` to avoid rewriting `EXAMPLE`: `... print FS $2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

This script, with first arg is the string to test, can retrieve the biggest duplicate substring (i.e. "totototo" done "toto", not "to")

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
row_name="$1"
#test duplicate from the longest to the smallest, by how many we need to split the string ?
for (( i=2; i<${#row_name}; i++ ))
do
  match="True"
  #continue test only if it's mathematically possible
  if (( ${#row_name} % i )); then
    continue
  fi
  #length of the potential duplicate substring
  len_sub=$(( ${#row_name} / i ))
  #test if the first substring is equal to each others
  for (( s=1; s<i; s++ ))
  do
    if ! [ "${row_name:0:${len_sub}}" = "${row_name:$((len_sub * s)):${len_sub}}" ]; then
      match="False"
      break
   fi
  done
  #each substring are equal, so return string without duplicate
  if [ $match = "True" ]; then
    row_name="${row_name:0:${len_sub}}"
    break
  fi
done
echo "$row_name"
```